# how can I reinstall ubuntu without internet connection

Tags: 12.04

I was installing updates and ubuntu crashed. Now I don't have the internet connection anymore. How can I install ubuntu back without internet connection?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Answer (score 0):

Download a liveCD from anoter computer and burn a CD.

Comment: Is there another way? everything seems to work except the internet, Any other idea?

Comment: @user146009 Edit your question or post a new question and include wireless specs